# Cast array to structure and vice-versa where every field has the same primitive type

Tags: c++

If I have a structure where every field has the same type, can I safely cast it to an array of the field type ?

```
struct A // 5 floats
{
    float a, b, c;
    float d;
    float e;
};

struct B // 5 floats
{
    float a[4]; // arrays?
    float b;
};

struct C // 9 floats
{
    B b; // other classes?
    float x, y, z, zz;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    
    float& fa = reinterpret_cast<float&>(a); // Safe?
    float& fa = reinterpret_cast<float&>(b); // Safe?
    float& fc = reinterpret_cast<float&>(c); // Safe?
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if it breaks strict aliasing or not. My gut feeling is saying yes. And that leads me to wonder *why* you're doing such casts? What is the actual underlying problem you need to solve? Why do you think casts like that would solve the underlying problem? This feels very much like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Also, you forgot one case: Inheritance (like e.g. `struct D : B`)

Comment: This is to store my own custom type in OpenCV matrix like this one : `struct SomeData { Vector2f pos; float distance; };` to use `cv::Mat_<SomeData>`. I want to be sure it is compatible with a 3-channels matrix of float. This is more meaningfull than `cv::Vec3f`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes but in this case I won't need it. But it may be useful to know.

Comment: And also isn't there problems related to padding / alignment if the count of variables is an odd variable ? (3 float, 5 floats, etc...)

Comment: It's unlikely that there will be padding between `float` members, but likely in the `C` structure between the `b` and `x` members. Also there might be padding at the end of the structure, but never at the beginning (so for example `&a` is guaranteed to be the same address as `&a.a`, but the types will of course be different).

Comment: No, you're not allowed to do that. Add an abstraction layer on top of `Vec3f`, for instance with accessor functions.

Answer (score 0):

##### tl;dr:

- `reinterpret_cast<float&>(a)` is legal, because `A` and `A::a` are [pointer-interconvertible](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.compound#4)
- `reinterpret_cast<float&>(b)` and `reinterpret_cast<float&>(c)` are **NOT** legal, because an array object and its first element are not pointer-interconvertible
- reinterpret_casting to a reference-to-array would be legal, i.e.:

  - `float (&fb)[4] = reinterpret_cast<float(&)[4]>(b);`
  - `float (&fc)[4] = reinterpret_cast<float(&)[4]>(c);`

---

##### Explanation

First lets look at the rules for reinterpret_cast when references are involved; this is covered by:

[7.6.1.10 Reinterpret cast [expr.reinterpret.cast]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.reinterpret.cast#11)

> <sup>(11)</sup> A glvalue of type *T1*, designating an object *x*, can be cast to the type “reference to *T2*” if an expression of type “pointer to *T1*” can be explicitly converted to the type “pointer to *T2*” using a `reinterpret_­cast`. The result is that of `*reinterpret_­cast<T2 *>(p)` where *p* is a pointer to *x* of type “pointer to *T1*”. No temporary is created, no copy is made, and no constructors ([[class.ctor]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.ctor)) or conversion functions ([[class.conv]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.conv)) are called.

This basically means that a reinterpret_cast to a reference results in a usable value, as long as a reinterpret_cast to a pointer would result in a usable value.

In your case this would mean that if `reinterpret_cast<float*>(&a)` would be legal, then `reinterpret_cast<float&>(a)` would be as well.

So let's check if the result of `reinterpret_cast<float*>(&a)` is usable; the rule that applies in this case is:

[7.6.1.10 Reinterpret cast [expr.reinterpret.cast]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.reinterpret.cast#7)

> <sup>(7)</sup> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type. When a prvalue *v* of object pointer type is converted to the object pointer type “pointer to *cv* *T*”, the result is `static_­cast<cv T*>(static_­cast<cv void*>(v))`.

So `reinterpret_cast<float*>(&a)` would be interpreted as:

```cpp
static_cast<float*>(static_cast<void*>(&a))
```

All pointers can be converted to `void*` according to [7.3.12 Pointer conversions [conv.ptr]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/conv.ptr#2), so the inner `static_cast` would be no problem.

For the `static_cast<float*>(...)` we need to check the rules for static_casts:
[7.6.1.9 Static cast[expr.static.cast]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.static.cast#13)

> <sup>(13)</sup> A prvalue of type “pointer to *cv1* *void*” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to *cv2* *T*”, where *T* is an object type and *cv2* is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, *cv1*. If the original pointer value represents the address *A* of a byte in memory and *A* does not satisfy the alignment requirement of *T*, then the resulting pointer value is unspecified. Otherwise, if the original pointer value points to an object *a*, and there is an object *b* of type *T* (ignoring cv-qualification) that is [pointer-interconvertible](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.compound#def:pointer-interconvertible) with *a*, the result is a pointer to *b*. Otherwise, the pointer value is unchanged by the conversion.

- We don't change the cv-qualification (const, volatile) with this cast, so that's no problem;
- Alignment is also not an issue, because `A` must have an aligment that's equal to or greater than the alignment of `float` (because it contains a float value)
- So the only condition we need to worry about is if `A` and `float` are pointer-interconvertible; if they are then using the result of `reinterpret_cast<float&>(a)` would be well-formed, otherwise the pointer value would be unchanged, i.e. accessing that reference would be undefined behaviour.

Pointer-interconvertability is covered by:
[6.8.3 Compound types [basic.compound]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.compound#4)

> <sup>(4)</sup> Two objects *a* and *b* are *pointer-interconvertible* if:
>
> - <sup>(4.1)</sup> they are the same object, or
> - <sup>(4.2)</sup> one is a union object and the other is a non-static data member of that object ([[class.union]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.union)), or
> - <sup>(4.3)</sup> one is a standard-layout class object and the other is the first non-static data member of that object, or, if the object has no non-static data members, any base class subobject of that object ([[class.mem]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.mem)), or
> - <sup>(4.4)</sup> there exists an object c such that a and c are pointer-interconvertible, and c and b are pointer-interconvertible.
>
> If two objects are pointer-interconvertible, then they have the same address, and it is possible to obtain a pointer to one from a pointer to the other via a `reinterpret_­cast`.
>
> [*Note 4*: An array object and its first element are not pointer-interconvertible, even though they have the same address. — *end note*]

Note that `A`, `B` and `C` in your example are standard-layout classes; i.e.:

```cpp
static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<A>);
static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<B>);
static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<C>);
```

- For `float& fa = reinterpret_cast<float&>(a);` we can apply (4.3); A is a standard-layout-type, and `A::a` is the first non-static data member of A.
  ⟶ `float& fa = reinterpret_cast<float&>(a);` is legal, due to pointer interconvertability; `fa` will refer to `a.a`
- The result of `float& fb = reinterpret_cast<float&>(b);` and `float& fc = reinterpret_cast<float&>(c);` can **NOT** be used; array objects and their first member are not pointer-interconvertible, so we are not allowed to reinterpret_cast to float.

Note that we can get a reference to the array itself though:

- `float (&fb)[4] = reinterpret_cast<float(&)[4]>(b);` would be legal; `fb` would refer to `b.a` (again covered by (4.3))
- `float (&fc)[4] = reinterpret_cast<float(&)[4]>(c);` would also be legal.
  This is covered by (4.4) - `C` is pointer-interconvertible with `B` and `B` is pointer-interconvertible with `float[4]`; so `fc` will refer to `c.b.a`.